# mysql datetime column manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I'm using phpmyadmin 3.5.2, codeigniter 2.1 for my website,

my problem comes when i try to load posts added in exact day, or when i want to show only date/time of that post.

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `worker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stats` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  KEY `worker_id` (`worker_id`,`patient_id`),
  KEY `patient_id` (`patient_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

---

my problem is manipulating this 'time' column, as i need to display for example

1) table that shows todays post (is use

```
Select * from posts where date(`time`) = date(NOW())
```

2) table to show todays post but time column return ONLY (TIME)
and thats my main problem as if i do

```
select time from posts
```

return both date and time, and i only want to return time from that column,yet still be able to use

```
where date('time') =date(now()) condition !.
```

so is there a better way to do this ?even if i can do this in php still fine by me!.

OR is it better if i split both time and date into 2 different columns ?

-------- 2nd part of question is for codeigniter----------

Model

```
$this->db->select('patients.name,workers.dr_name,time(posts.time),posts.stats');
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->join('workers','posts.worker_id=workers.worker_id','left');
$this->db->join('patients','posts.patient_id=patients.patient_id','left');
$this->db->where('date(`time`) = date(NOW())');
return $this->db->get();
```

Controller

```
$this->load->model('Posts_model');
$q=$this->Visits_model->allvisits;
$this->load->library('table');
$this->load->view('welcome_message');
$qq=$q->result_array();
$qq=array('patient','Doctor','Time','Stats');   
$this->table->set_heading($qq);
$this->table->set_caption('Todays Posts');
echo $this->table->generate($q);
```

---

how can i remove last where condition in Model (where date=Now) and use php to sort this insteed ? do i have to loop the results ? or is there a cleaner way to do it ?
thanks

Comment: thanks to eggyal i now can get only time in query :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function returns only the `DATE` part of a `TIMESTAMP`, its [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function returns only the `TIME` part:

```sql
SELECT TIME(time) FROM posts WHERE DATE(time) = CURRENT_DATE
```